# Set volume of ALSA stream plug-in

Tags: c, alsa

I need to be able to set the volume of my ALSA stream (snd_pcm_t from the PCM Interface)

I write ALSA stream public functions:

```
int alsa_thread_startup(const char *pdevice, const char *cdevice, int latency,
                FILE *__error_fp,
                int verbose);

void alsa_thread_stop(void);
```

were pdevice is playback device and cdevice is capture device.

I see no connection between snd_pcm_t and the control interface. Am i using the wrong API?

amixer controls -c0 (mainboard):

```
numid=9,iface=MIXER,name='Master Mono Playback Switch'
numid=10,iface=MIXER,name='Master Mono Playback Volume'
numid=1,iface=MIXER,name='Master Playback Switch'
numid=2,iface=MIXER,name='Master Playback Volume'
numid=24,iface=MIXER,name='PCM Playback Switch'
numid=25,iface=MIXER,name='PCM Playback Volume'
numid=38,iface=MIXER,name='Surround Jack Mode'
numid=7,iface=MIXER,name='Surround Playback Switch'
numid=8,iface=MIXER,name='Surround Playback Volume'
numid=3,iface=MIXER,name='Center Playback Switch'
numid=4,iface=MIXER,name='Center Playback Volume'
numid=5,iface=MIXER,name='LFE Playback Switch'
numid=6,iface=MIXER,name='LFE Playback Volume'
numid=18,iface=MIXER,name='Line Playback Switch'
numid=19,iface=MIXER,name='Line Playback Volume'
numid=20,iface=MIXER,name='CD Playback Switch'
numid=21,iface=MIXER,name='CD Playback Volume'
numid=17,iface=MIXER,name='Mic Boost (+20dB)'
numid=37,iface=MIXER,name='Mic Front Input Switch'
numid=30,iface=MIXER,name='Mic Select'
numid=15,iface=MIXER,name='Mic Playback Switch'
numid=16,iface=MIXER,name='Mic Playback Volume'
numid=13,iface=MIXER,name='Phone Playback Switch'
numid=14,iface=MIXER,name='Phone Playback Volume'
numid=22,iface=MIXER,name='Aux Playback Switch'
numid=23,iface=MIXER,name='Aux Playback Volume'
numid=29,iface=MIXER,name='Mono Output Select'
numid=26,iface=MIXER,name='Capture Source'
numid=27,iface=MIXER,name='Capture Switch'
numid=28,iface=MIXER,name='Capture Volume'
numid=31,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Con Mask'
numid=32,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Pro Mask'
numid=35,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback AC97-SPSA'
numid=33,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Default'
numid=41,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Source'
numid=34,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Switch'
numid=40,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Capture Switch'
numid=11,iface=MIXER,name='Beep Playback Switch'
numid=12,iface=MIXER,name='Beep Playback Volume'
numid=39,iface=MIXER,name='Channel Mode'
numid=36,iface=MIXER,name='Duplicate Front'
numid=42,iface=MIXER,name='External Amplifier'
numid=43,iface=PCM,name='Playback Channel Map'
```

amixer controls -c1 (saa7134):

```
numid=2,iface=MIXER,name='Line Volume',index=1
numid=3,iface=MIXER,name='Line Volume',index=2
numid=5,iface=MIXER,name='Line Capture Switch',index=1
numid=6,iface=MIXER,name='Line Capture Switch',index=2
numid=1,iface=MIXER,name='Video Volume'
numid=4,iface=MIXER,name='Video Capture Switch'
```

Comment: Do you know on which hardware you are running?

Comment: capture from tvtuner (saa7134-alsa) and output to mainboard sound card

Comment: Is it always one specific mainboard model?

Comment: pdevice = "default"  For example I start alsa thread with: alsa_thread_startup("default", "hw:1,0", 50, stderr, 1);

Comment: Show the output of `amixer controls`.

Comment: put in in first post

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct connection between a PCM device and the control interface.

Whether a control that affects only the PCM device exists is hardware dependent.
If it exists, it is often called "PCM Playback Volume". Search for this control by name.
(Please note that on all AC'97 any some HDA codecs, this control affects only the two front channels.)